# Assign as value of a variable the output of a proc summary

Tags: sas

I have one simple question.
I have a data set and I performed the following:

> ```
> proc means data=mydata sum;
>    var weight;
>    output out=all 
>    sum=overall;
>  run;
> ```

Now, I would like to "copy" the value of "sum", in another proc that is the following as the value of new_weight:

> ```
>     data test;
>        if 0 then set test;
>           if _n_=1 then 
>       do;
>      YEAR=2015;
>      HOSPITAL="A";
>      COUNTRY=.;
>      new_weight="I need to add the value of sum from proc means as above";
>   output;
>   end;
>   set db;
>  output;
> run;
> ```

Can anyone help me please? I don't want to copy manually the value of the "sum" variable because it will take different values every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if _n_ eq 1 then set overall;;
```